# zsh: killed for confd

Tags: zsh, confd

I tried installing confd using their official installation guide
https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Installation went okay without any error. However, when I am trying to run `confd` using terminal, I am getting error `zsh: killed     confd`

Screenshot
[image]

I am using macOS big sur. I need help to debug why this process is being killed as soon as I run this command. Although all applications are working fine from terminal. Please let me know if any more details need to be added to this post.

Comment: I don't know `confd`, but are you sure that you can run it under your own user id, and not via `sudo`? Perhaps it tries to access something where it has no permissions to do so. Did you manage to use confd successfully on a different platform? Otherwise, are you sure that you have downloaded the macOS version of confd and that the binary is not damaged?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue reported for confd binary not working for OS X Big Sur.
https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/issues/842

I followed the instructions on their instructions given in [Readme.md](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd#building) and it worked as expected.